# Using MVC6 in .Net Core 2.0 select tag not displaying placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of changing over my custom web application template for visual studio to use .Net Core and MVC 6.

On my registration screen, my dropdown for Gender will not display "Select Gender", no doubt due to slight difference in how MVC 6 tag works vs MVC 5.

In my current template using the code below works perfectly and displays as shown

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender,
                       new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))),
                       "Select Gender",
                       new
                          {
                             @class = "form-control",
                             id = "validation-gender"
                          })
```

[image: Register with Gender correct]

I have tried a few different iterations but either get errors, or the current version shown below which works, but doesn't display "Select Gender".

MVC 6 version

```
 <select asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" id="validation-gender" 
         asp-items="@(new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)),"Select Gender"))">

  </select>
```

[image: Register with Gender incorrect]

Can someone advise me on how to get "Select Gender" to display in the MVC 6 version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the null `<option>` element manually in your `<select>` tags

```
<select asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" id="validation-gender" 
    asp-items="@(new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)),"Select Gender"))">
    <option value="">Select Gender</option>
</select>
```

As a side note, you can also use `asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Gender>()">` instead of `asp-items="@(new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))` which also has the added advantage of respecting any `[Display]` attribute applies to your `enum` values

Comment: Mueke...thank you, meaning I can add a "Select Gender" property in my enum and add the [Display] attribute to it? and then your suggested version will automatically use that as its initial  default display value?

Comment: No, you do not add `SelectGender" as a property of your enum. You add it as per my answer.

Comment: The 2nd part of my answer means you can do, for example, `public enum Gender { Male, Female, [Display(Name="Trans Person")]TransPerson }` and the 3rd option will be rendered with as "Trans Person" with the space

Comment: Yes, I understand the manual addition of the select option. Your side note said "which also has the added advantage of respecting any [Display] attribute applies to your enum values". Can you elaborate on the use of the Display attribute?

Comment: See my previous comment for an example